# Training like a bull

Tags: muscle, strength, strength-training, conditioning, lower-body-strength

[image]

What are the benefits of training like a real bull, by moving HEAVY things on the daily?
Not full body every day, just heavy carries to overload the legs and traps.
Like yoke carries alternated with barbell/bag  incline caries,weighted climbing and dragging/pushing my car(1800kg)

Comment: You mean like a strong man? And everyday the whole body? How advanced are you in lifting/strength based sport?

Comment: Overload means building the muscle not by using it with a lot of reps but making it sore by slightly tearing it under high stress?

Comment: my actual yoke is at 176 kilograms , 2,2 times my bodyweight

Answer (score 3):

(Partial answer as proof/studies referenced missing)

**Benefits of regular heavy training**

- Your body will take on musclemass fast if regeneration is timed right.
- Your body will adapt after a while, see strongmen

**Downsides**

- Not suitable and unnecessary for beginners. That much stimulus is not needed but increases risk of injury and bad form
- Bulls are heavy, their work must be seen compared to their mass and body type. You might lift wrong or too much
- Bulls are ideally moving all day and their physical work is not just an hour in the gym but usually a way bigger amount of their time.
- Heavy weights put a lot of stress on your joints even with proper form. This can result in health problems after a long time.
- Being natural: Tearing or extreme soreness in muscles will result in them needing multiple days to recover. Doing so everyday with the same muscles will result in overtraining.
- Using highly anabolic drugs: You would likely not be overtraining but as joints etc are lagging behind musclegrowth you would risk injury with heavy weights